# Form not submitting without redirecting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, sms

I want to send sms on click without page reload and redirecting but the form not working without redirecting to action page. Here is my code.

**Page containing form**

```
<div class="blog">
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="whatever">
<input type="text" name="tono" maxlength="10">
<input type="submit" value="SEND SMS" id="sendit">
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sendit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./example.php",
data: $(form).serialize();
}).done(function(response) {
alert(response);
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
</div>
```

**example.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush(true);

include_once "class.curl.php";
include_once "class.sms.php";
include_once "cprint.php";

$smsapp=new sms();
$smsapp->setGateway('way2sms');
$myno='XXXXXXX';
$p='XXXXXXXX';
$tonum=$_POST['tono'];
$mess=$_POST['message'];

cprint("Logging in ..\n");
$ret=$smsapp->login($myno,$p);

if (!$ret) {
cprint("Error Logging In");
exit(1);
}

print("Logged in Successfully\n");

print("Sending SMS ..\n");
$ret=$smsapp->send($tonum,$mess);

if (!$ret) {
print("Error in sending message");
exit(1);
}

print("Message sent");

?>
```

This reloads the page but doesn't submit the form and if i add action attribute to form it redirects to example.php and successfully sends sms.

Comment: use even,preventDefault() for stop reloadig

Comment: Thats not the issue, he is returning false in the handler. The problem is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

I see you are returning false in the handler, which is basically the same as using `event.preventDefault()`, but this is not working because you have a syntax error (a semicolon that should not be there):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sendit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./example.php",
            data: $(form).serialize() // You have ";" here, and it's causing the rest of the code to fail.
        }).done(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Good catch! I totally missed that. Code indentation sure does help here.

Comment: But its not working now also after correcting syntax error. Doesn't send any sms. It sends sms if i add action action attribute in form and if it redirects to action page.